# How can i show percentage instead of values in barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

There is my below dataframe and code.

```
Gender    Actual    Predicted   new_salary
Female  47390.03    47344.005   48870.454
Male    49538.83    49584.995   49538.829
```

My code:

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,8),width = 0.8,color = colors_list, edgecolor=None)

for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.annotate(f'{height}', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center')
```

[image: result of my code]

**Objective**: Is there a way to show how much % has increased in `new_salary` when compared with actual values and predicted values? Instead of the values, I need the percentage change.

Comment: are you talking about the annotations, y-axis, or both?

Comment: Yes, annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check the Snippet to show percentage instead of values.
Just converted your `dataframe` columns to percentage format.

```
columns = ['Actual','Predicted','new_salary']
df[columns] = df[columns].div(df[columns].sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100).round({'Actual': 2, 'Predicted': 2,'new_salary': 2})
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [['Female', 47390.03,47344.005,48870.454], ['male',49538.83,49584.995,49538.829]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Gender', 'Actual','Predicted','new_salary']) 
colors_list=['green','blue','red']
posy=np.arange(len(df['Gender']))

columns = ['Actual','Predicted','new_salary']
df[columns] = df[columns].div(df[columns].sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100).round({'Actual': 2, 'Predicted': 2,'new_salary': 2})
print(df)
"""
   Gender  Actual  Predicted  new_salary
0  Female   33.00      32.97       34.03
1    male   33.32      33.35       33.32
"""
ax=df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(15,8),
            width = 0.8,
            color = colors_list,
            edgecolor=None)

for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    height = p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy()
    ax.annotate(f'{height}%\n', (x + width/2, y + height*1.02), ha='center',va='center')  
plt.show()
```